# convert timezone for already added jobs in apscheduler table

Tags: apscheduler

I added my schedules in apscheduler(MySQL Database) in UTC time format but now I need to migrate all my schedules to a different time zone like CST or any other time zone inside the database so that they trigger with the modified timezone and not in UTC.

Code snippet:

```
scheduler_obj.add_job(schedule_request, "cron",id=str(job_obj.request_id), 
year="*",month="*",day="*",week="*",day_of_week="*",hour="*", minute="*/5",
second="0", start_date="2018-01-01 03:00:00", end_date="2019-01-01 03:00:00",
misfire_grace_time=15,timezone=ltz)
```

The Best approach here?

Comment: Are you sure that you can add timezone in .add_job()  as it is not listed in the documentation [here] (http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job)  ? You definitely can add timezone of the scheduler like below
`scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone="Asia/Bishkek")`

Comment: @CholponAbdyzhaparova Issue is, already job is started for the schedule in UTC time format, i want to convert that time format in MySQL